# How can I retrieve files from document library in powerautomate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, flow, power-automate

I have a document library. I want to use power automate connectors  to get files from document library and do some operation on those files (Excel, word)?

How  can I achieve through power automate?

Comment: Do you want to get all files from document library? what type of operations you want to perform on files? There might be some limitations using Power Automate. can you please add more details to your question, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have unique id generator in sp library .. so I want to retreive the files which is having same ID ... and filter operation is not allowed in Files

Comment: You can use filters in "Get files" action as well as "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action. try solutions given in my answer & let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Get files is only for properties I believe ..we cant get attachment here ..and can we use filter for file type in rest call?? can you share your solution link ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward action using SharePoint connector to get the all files in a document library.

You can find all available actions at [SharePoint actions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers#sharepoint-actions) or [SharePoint connector - Actions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#actions).

But there are some workarounds to get the files in a particular folder or by using SharePoint REST APIs like below:

1. [Microsoft Flow – Retrieve All Files from SharePoint Library Folder & Send Email Attachment](https://mydevexperience.wordpress.com/2019/10/12/microsoft-flow-retrieve-all-files-from-sharepoint-library-folder-send-email-attachment/)
2. [Get all files in a SharePoint folder using Power Automate](https://sharepains.com/2020/03/12/get-all-files-in-a-sharepoint-folder/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to modify file content via Power Automate. You can get file content via the action [Get File Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers#get-file-content). However if you are trying to modify the content, that is well supported in Power Automate. You can update the file content with the [Update File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers#update-file) action. However it is needed to provide the content in a format Power Automate can recognize and handle. In most case, we can do a [copy and paste](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Update-SharePoint-File-in-a-Folder/td-p/189265), but not changing certain words or lines.

A video which may help:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Yhx7dAGFAw

Answer (score 0):

so actually I had find the solution..i will get files (properties) --> put filter ----> get file content by path ---> create item with the file content .For me get file content by path worked .